# Python Tkinter: How to add custom border to Pop-up window

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, border, frame

The following is a sample of my code. I do not understand why I cannot create a thin black border surrounding my pop-up window.

Note that I have purposely remove the default border using **self.top.overrideredirect(True)**. However, I want to re-create a thin layer.

Please try the following (Python 2.7):

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Frame, Toplevel, Label

class srcDestDescription(Frame):
   def __init__(self, parent):
      Frame.__init__(self, parent)
      self.top = Toplevel(parent)
      self.parent = parent
      self.top.overrideredirect(True)
      self.top.geometry('+%d+%d' % (350, 100))
      self.top.withdraw()
   def display(self):
      self.top.deiconify()
      topLabel = Label(self.top, text = "Hello World")
      topLabel.grid(column = 0, columnspan = 2, row = 0, sticky = 'NSWE', padx = 10, pady = (10, 5))
      topLabel.config(font = ('times', 14))

class Application(Frame):

   def __init__(self, parent):
      Frame.__init__(self, parent)
      self.parent = parent
      self.parent.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (300, 300, 0, 0))
      self.parent.resizable(0, 0)

      self.pack(expand = True)
      self.srcDestDescription = srcDestDescription(self)
      self.srcDestDescription.display()

def main():
   root = Tk()
   Application(root)
   root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: Trying to displaying a frame that is not placed, packed, or gridded is useless. A frame is made displayable within a Tk or Toplevel  (or descendent) with one of those geometry methods.  Toplevel.overrideredirect(True) in not about borders. It tells the window manager to ignore the Toplevel.

Comment: To revise the comment above, ignoring the Toplevel hides the entire Window frame with top bar including icon, title, and window buttons.  So if you mean window frame by border, you are right, but you must put something inside to see anything.  I am working on example code.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Frame, Toplevel, Label

class MyTop(Toplevel):
   def __init__(self, parent):
      Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
      self.overrideredirect(True)
      self.withdraw()
      self.geometry('+%d+%d' % (350, 100))
      topLabel = Label(self, text="Hello World",
                       borderwidth=1, relief='solid')
      topLabel.pack(padx=10, pady=(10, 5))
      topLabel.config(font = ('times', 14))

class Application(Frame):

   def __init__(self, parent):
      Frame.__init__(self, parent)
      self.parent = parent
      self.parent.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (300, 300, 0, 0))
      self.parent.resizable(0, 0)

      self.pack(expand = True)
      self.mytop = MyTop(self.parent)
      self.mytop.deiconify()

def main():
   root = Tk()
   Application(root)
   root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Code for a tool tip popup, based on Toplevel but with a class that is not a Toplevel subclass, can be found in Pythonxy/lib/idlelib/ToolTip.py.  (Copy this is you want to use it.)  Idle's CalltipWindow popup are similar but a bit more complicated.

Another way to get a thin-border popup is to use a Menu instance and `tk_popup(self, x, y, entry='')` (docstring "Post the menu at position X,Y with entry ENTRY.").  The typical use is for a right-click context menu, but you invent another use.  The Idle example is Pythonxy/Lib/idlelib/EditorWindow.py, EditorWindow.right_menu_event.

Comment: You simply configured the Label with borderwidth=1, relief='solid' in the example. What I want is a border surrounding the pop-up please

Comment: A border around the popup is exactly what one sees with the code above.  You could instead skip the geometry for the Toplevel and pack a visible sized frame or canvas inside the toplevel and put whatever widgets you want wherever you want inside the container.